# How to move a marker on a google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps

I am learning the Google Maps API and I am trying to move an object on the map. I created a test page which shows a marker on start, but after calling a function which increases the longitude it removes the marker from the map. There is no error in the console. Can someone look at my code and help me figure out why this is happening?
Javascript file:

```
var app = angular.module('angularGoogleMapsTestApp', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

var increment = 2.02;
var startingLongitude = -122.44;
var startingLatitude = 37.769;

  app.controller('angularGoogleMapCtrl', function ($scope, $log, $rootScope) {

$scope.map = {center: {latitude: 37.7699298, longitude: -122.4469157}, zoom: 12};
$scope.markers = [];

$scope.removeMarkers = function () {
    $scope.markers = [];
}

function init() {
    $scope.markers.push(
            {
                id: 0,
                latitude: startingLatitude,
                longitude: startingLongitude
            });

    $log.info(JSON.stringify($scope.markers));
}

$scope.moveMarker = function () {
    var old = $scope.markers[0].longitude;
     $scope.markers.splice(0, 1);
    $scope.markers.push(
            {
                id: 0,
                latitude: startingLatitude,
                longitude: (old + increment)
            });
    $log.info(JSON.stringify($scope.markers));
 };

  init();

});
```

and html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>ngMap Tests</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="bower_components/angularjs/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lodash/dist/lodash.js"></script>
<script src='bower_components/angular-google-maps/dist/angular-    google-maps.js'></script>
<script src="angularGoogleMapsTestApp.js"></script>
<style>
    .angular-google-map-container { height: 400px; }

</style>
</head>
<body ng-app="angularGoogleMapsTestApp">
<h3>Angular Google Maps Test</h3>

<p>Test showing adding and removing markers on Angular Google Maps
    (from: <a href="http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/">
        Angular Google Maps</a>)</p>

<div ng-controller="angularGoogleMapCtrl">
    <input ng-click="moveMarker()" type="button" value="moveMarker">
    <input ng-click="removeMarkers()" type="button" value="Remove markers">

    <div style="height:500px">
        <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom'>
            <ui-gmap-markers models="markers" coords="'self'" modelsbyref="false"/>
        </ui-gmap-google-map>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Angular Google maps v1.2.0 or higher, your marker objects require an `idKey`, [described here in the docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/markers). You can change your current `id` key with `idKey` like so:

```
$scope.markers.push({
    idKey: 0,
    latitude: startingLatitude,
    longitude: startingLongitude
});
```